# SQL Select with join query works but delete does not work

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
I have two tables Table1 and Table2. I compared thes tables using the query below. SELECT 

Select Table1.ID
     FROM Table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.ID =Table2.ID
     WHERE Table2.ID IS NULL
```

and got 1508 records that exist in Table1 but not in Table2.
Now I wanted to delete these records in Table2. This is the code I used below

```
 DELETE Table1.*
    FROM Table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.ID =Table2.ID
     WHERE Table2.ID IS NULL
```

This is the error I am get Could not delete from specified tables. I realize something is wrong with my sql, but where. I thought this DELETE was specifying a table not tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM table2
)
```

Comment: did you specify constraints on your `ID`?

Comment: No I didnt. I had them removed. Table2 has over 80000 records. When I do a SELECT with LEFT JOIN it doesnt take time however  the solution you suggested is taking long to execute.

Comment: are `ID` primary key from both tables?

Comment: Not on Table2. However on Table1 it is the primary key.

Comment: if you make `ID` as primary key in table2 then it will increase the performance. What's the reason why `ID` is not primary key? Is it because it can contain `duplicate` values? Well, if that's the case you can create [NON-UNIQUE Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177891(v=office.12).aspx) on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18156/discussion-between-sithelo-and-john-woo)